# How to prove that all primitive polynomials are irreducible

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a **finite** field, and $F[X]$ set of all polynomials in $F$,  how to prove  that: why all primitive polynomials $\;$ $f \in F[X]$ $\;$ must be an **irreducible**.

**Note:**
*Polynomial primitive is an irreductible polynomial over F, that have a root in the extension field of F and that's root is primive in the extension (Generator Element)*.

Comment: 1. Note the terminology - $F[x]$ is the set of polynomials (in one variable) **over** $F$ (polynomials **in** $F$ are just the constant polynomials). 2. What is your definition of primitive polynomial ?

Comment: polynomial primive is an irreductible polynomial over $F$, that have a root in the extension field of $F$ and that's root is primive in the extension (generator element).

Comment: Then by definition a primitive polynomial is irreducible, I don't understand your question

Comment: how to prove this definition?

Comment: I thought that was the definition of a primitive polynomial (one that is irreducible).

Comment: this is one of definitions, but we need to prove it.

Comment: @ro0xandr Please include the definition of a primitive polynomial in the question.